# Making call jquery object function called history

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var history = {
    stack   : [],
    counter : -1,
    add     : function(item){
        this.stack[++this.counter] = item;
        this.doSomethingWith(item);

        // delete anything forward of the counter
        this.stack.splice(this.counter+1);
    },
    undo : function(){
        this.doSomethingWith(this.stack[--this.counter]);
    },
    redo : function(){
        this.doSomethingWith(this.stack[++this.counter]);
    },
    doSomethingWith : function(item){
        // show item
    }
};
```

When I try use that on this way it's not working;

```
var item = $('#myDiv');
history.add(item);
```

I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

How can I solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YqMd8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you picked a bad name for your object. There is build in `History` object available as `window.history`. So rename yours to something else and it should work. For example:

```
var appHistory = {
    stack   : [],
    counter : -1,
    ...
};
```

You could also fix it by wrapping your code into IIFE for example, so that `history` would become a local variable. But I would still recommend picking less confusing name.

Answer (score 1):

It works well if you put this behind the other code:

```
var item = $('myDiv');
history.add(item);
```

If you put it in front the function is not yet defined.
Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LqrpW/

Answer (score 0):

`$('myDiv')` replace with `$('.myDiv')` or `$('#myDiv')`

Comment: I think that was a typo in the question, which is fixed by now.

Comment: Not, the problem wasn't in the $('myDiv')